# Relay Simulation in Multisim - output voltage shortly above supply voltage -how?

Tags: diodes, relay, simulation, oscilloscope

Hi I am trying to do a simulation of  a relay with the following model:

A saquare wave voltage  - 5V - 10 Hz

- An inductor coil 60mH
- A transistor
- A diode
- Resistance R1 = 1.8k Ohm
- Resistance R2 = 10 Ohm

I have connected the Relay model to an oscilloscope. My question is that when I run the simulation in Multisim, I see that the voltage at the input A (the voltage from the diode - the top most in the graph below) in the oscilloscope in the beginning  oscillating above (overshoot) the supply voltage of 5V before it reaches a steady stage.  Why is this happening??

[image]

I have connected the Relay model to an oscilloscope. My question is that when I run the simulation in Multisim, I see that the voltage at the input A (the voltage from the diode - the top most in the graph below in orange) in the oscilloscope in the beginning  oscillating above (overshoot) the supply voltage of 5V before it reaches a steady stage.  Why is this happening??

[image: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/by7nt.png]

Comment: D1 is not connected to the circuit at both ends ... there is no power supply

Comment: Hi jsotola - thanks for the comment - I am new. I have corrected it so it is connected (see edited question) but I still see the same "phenomena" with the output voltage shortly going above the supply voltage in the beginning..

Comment: you still do not have a DC power supply